typeError ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE string similarity package error
global.FolderPath = path.join(os.homedir(), "data")
global.DataPath = path.join(global.FolderPath, "data.json")

let Data: {[key: string]: Configuration} = {};

if (fs.existsSync(global.DataPath)) {
    const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(global.DataPath, "utf-8");
    if (typeof fileContent === "string") {
        try {
            Data = JSON.parse(fileContent) as {[key: string]: Configuration};
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error parsing JSON:", error);
        }
    } else {
        console.error("File content is not a string.");
    }
} else {
    console.warn(`File does not exist at ${global.DataPath}. Creating a new file.`);
}

// If the folder doesn't exist, create it and write an empty object to the file
if (!fs.existsSync(global.FolderPath)) {
    fs.mkdirSync(global.FolderPath);
    fs.writeFileSync(global.DataPath, "{}");
}

process.on("unhandledRejection", (error) => {
    console.error(error);
    // Assuming log is defined elsewhere
    log("Unhandled Rejection Found!", "PROMISE.ERROR");
});

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, or Array or an Array-like Object. Received undefined
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
    at Function.from (node:buffer:330:9)
    at DiscordAuthWebsocket._decryptPayload (C:\Users\V\Downloads\discord-owo-selfbot-main\node_modules\discord.js-selfbot-v13\src\util\RemoteAuth.js:335:28)
    at DiscordAuthWebsocket._findRealToken (C:\Users\V\Downloads\discord-owo-selfbot-main\node_modules\discord.js-selfbot-v13\src\util\RemoteAuth.js:473:27)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE' '''

Here the code asks for a token value as a string and when i input it it shows me an error of invalid argument type as above in the image..
I tried to input a string but also it showed a npm warn about the string similarity package 4.0.4 i wonder if thats the issue

this error seems to come from something related to the discord.js-selfbot-v13 package. But nothing in the code you show is remotely connected to that package.

So chances are high you didn't initialize that package correctly. Or maybe your Data object you are trying to read contains the config for this package, but its content doesn't fit the expectations of that package?

I can provide you with the selfbot code can you look through the src dependencies and to add ot worked perfectly fine for the first time and then when i reopened the terminal it shows this error

Its a public archive in github too - (https://github.com/LongAKolangle/discord-owo-selfbot/discussions/15 )
